# Filesystem nearly full, unable to find which files are taking up all the space

Tags: server, partitioning, filesystem

If i run df -h i get the following output:

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                 48G     0   48G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               9.5G  1.2M  9.5G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/sealikreela04--vg-root   97G   85G  7.8G  92% /
tmpfs                                48G     0   48G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                48G     0   48G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
san-zfs-pool1                        20T   16T  4.1T  80% /data-dir
tmpfs                               9.5G     0  9.5G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see / is 92% full and i want to find which files are taking up all of the space. So i installed **ncdu** and ran the command "ncdu -x / --exclude /data-dir" and got the following output:

```
4.6 GiB [##########] /var                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.3 GiB [##        ] /usr
  837.2 MiB [#         ] /lib
  114.5 MiB [          ] /boot
   35.3 MiB [          ] /home
   11.8 MiB [          ] /sbin
   11.1 MiB [          ] /bin
    6.6 MiB [          ] /etc
  124.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
   44.0 KiB [          ] /root
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /media
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
>   0.0   B [          ] /sys
>   0.0   B [          ] /run
>   0.0   B [          ] /proc
>   0.0   B [          ] /dev
```

As you can see i get nowhere near 85G. I've checked that the filesystem still have inodes to use and they were at around 2% used.

Does anyone have any idea how can i trace what files are taking upp all of the space on / ?

Comment: `sudo du -xh -d 3 /  | sort -h -r | egrep -v '*K|*M'`

Comment: If you have a graphical desktop environment, an alternative is to [install and] use **baobab**.